# Identify KNO3 and KH2PO4 at home

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment

I am not expert in chemistry. I need to find a way to identify a $\ce{KNO3}$ and $\ce{KH2PO4}$ powder at home. I suspect the seller gave me the wrong powder. What is a simple way to test between these compounds at home?

Comment: KNO3 is much better soluble in water.

Comment: Given the number of votes and views gained in such a short time, I hope that you will edit this question to be more clear, As-is I don't know how to answer it.

Answer (score 9):

In the absence of other chemicals you can utilize the fact that nitrates(V) are much stronger oxidizing agents than phosphates(V).
You can soak a piece of newspaper in a saturated solution of the salt, let it dry well in a ventilated place and try to ignite it.

If the salt was $\ce{KNO3}$, it will burn vigorously and fast (that's why kids are often using paper soaked in sodium nitrate as primitive fuse for home-made firecrackers and rockets).

$\ce{KH2PO4}$ doesn't promote combustion of paper, so it will burn normally or even slower.

Comment: Okay. The burning technique is surely simple for detecting $\ce{KNO3}$. Thanks!

Comment: @sanch21 It looks like you used an unregistered account to ask this question. I just want to point out that you can request to have your [accounts merged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) and be able to accept this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Well, given that one is a weak acid and the other is the salt of a strong base and a strong acid, the pH of a solution of the powder should tell you which it is. If it's $\ce{KNO3}$ it should neutral, and if it's $\ce{KH2PO4}$ it should be acidic. Just need some pH paper, which you could probably buy at a pool supply store.

Comment: This could work, but KH2PO4 solution would have pH somewhere around 4.7 - water used at home might be as acidic as this, I guess.

Comment: @Mithoron so be sure to use the pH-paper to test regular water too.

Answer (score 4):

Touch medium samples of both salts with a glowing ember. No noticable effect would be observed on contact with $\ce{KH2PO4}$. Contact with $\ce{KNO3}$ shall produce noticeable flame.

Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJRqJ145dyM